# How to use setArguments() and getArguments() methods in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments: (1)Frag1 (2)Frag2.

## Frag1

```
bundl = new Bundle();
bundl.putStringArrayList("elist", eList);

Frag2 dv = new Frag2();
dv.setArguments(bundl);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.the_fragg,dv);
ft.show(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_fragg)); 
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

How do I get this data in Frag2?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have a method called `getArguments()` that belongs to `Fragment` class.

Answer (score 197):

Just call `getArguments()` in your `Frag2`'s `onCreateView()` method:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup containerObject,
         Bundle savedInstanceState){
         //here is your arguments
         Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 
  
        //here is your list array 
        String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("elist");   
     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Best practice is read and save arguments in `onCreate` method. It's worse to do it in `onCreateView` because `onCreateView` will be called each time when fragment creates view (for example each time when fragment pops from backstack)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle arguments = getArguments(); 
}
```

Comment: It is returning null in my case, any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: You're putting **ArrayList** into the bundle, but getting a String Array. You should do `bundle.getStringArrayList("elist");`

Comment: You forgot the return statement: `return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Oncreateview calling all the time. So simply call getarguments in oncreate() method. It will call only when the fragment is destroyed or newly created time.

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan @HabeebPerwad Why are you using `getArguments()`  in `onCreateView`, not in `onCreate`?

Answer (score 43):

**Eg: Add data:-**

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("latitude", latitude);
   bundle.putString("longitude", longitude);
   bundle.putString("board_id", board_id);
   MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
   mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Eg: Get data :-**

```
String latitude =  getArguments().getString("latitude")
```

Answer (score 8):

in Frag1:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putStringArray("arrayname that use to retrive in frag2",StringArrayObject);

Frag2.setArguments(b);
```

in Frag2:

```
Bundle b = getArguments();

String[] stringArray = b.getStringArray("arrayname that passed in frag1");
```

It's that simple.

Answer (score 6):

### Instantiating the Fragment the correct way!

> `getArguments()` `setArguments()` methods seem very useful when it comes
>   to instantiating a Fragment using a static method.
>   ie `Myfragment.createInstance(String msg)`

How to do it?

**Fragment code**

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private String displayMsg;
    private TextView text;

    public static MyFragment createInstance(String displayMsg)
    {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.setString("KEY",displayMsg);
        fragment.setArguments(args);           //set
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        displayMsg = getArguments().getString("KEY"):    // get 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInlater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle bundle){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.id.placeholder,parent,false);
        text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        text.setText(displayMsg)    // show msg
        returm view;
   }

}
```

> Let's say you want to pass a String while creating an Instance. This
>   is how you will do it.

```
MyFragment.createInstance("This String will be shown in textView");
```

## Read More

**1)** [Why Myfragment.getInstance(String msg) is preferred over new MyFragment(String msg)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)
**2)** [Sample code on Fragments](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/Fragment%20Related%20Stuff)

Comment: android.os.Bundle doesn't have setString. Do you mean putString() ?

Answer (score 2):

for those like me who are looking to send objects other than primitives, 
since you can't create a parameterized constructor in your fragment, just add a setter accessor in your fragment, this always works for me.

Comment: That's a wrong way. If a fragment recreates, it will lose those parameters. Parameters sent to the fragment should be serializable, passed through `setArguments()`. Nonserializable parameters can be set with setter, but it should again be called on activity/fragment recreate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigation components and navigation graph create a bundle like this

```
val bundle = bundleOf(KEY to VALUE) // or whatever you would like to create the bundle
```

then when navigating to the other fragment use this:

```
findNavController().navigate(
        R.id.action_navigate_from_frag1_to_frag2,
        bundle
    )
```

and when you land the destination fragment u can access that bundle using

```
Bundle b = getArguments()// in Java
```

or

```
val b = arguments// in kotlin
```