# The correct way and place to restore bundle information on a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I have seen `Bundle`s restored in several of the Android callback methods, but in many cases there is manual creation and setting of `Bundle`s as on the [developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) website, in this case from an external message on `Fragment` creation:

```
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

In this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425568/how-to-use-setarguments-and-getarguments-methods-in-fragments), for example, bundle data is restored in the `onCreateView()` method.

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup containerObject,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //here is your arguments
        Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

        //here is your list array 
        String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("elist");   
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused about the `Bundle` data supplied with each callback method VS "other bundles":

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
```

and the **correct way and place to retrieve these different types of bundled data**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: @Y.S. Yes I did, thank you, I was still a bit confused about two things:

- Is there a particular reason **onCreateView()** is the correct method to retrieve "initial bundles" VS any of the other Fragment lifecycle callback methods?

- How do I know which Bundle is retrieved from the **getArguments()** method?

Comment: @Y.S. done (I still can't upvote your answer unfortunately due to rep<15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ways described above are exactly the correct way to

- initialize a new instance of the `Fragment` and pass the initial parameters.
- retrieve the initial parameters in the `Fragment`.

In other words, you're on the right track! It should work, and you should be pleased with yourself :)

**EDIT:**

- The `Bundle` can be retrieved in either `onCreateView()` or
  `onCreate()`. I'd prefer `onCreate()`, as it represents the creation
  of the `Fragment` instance and is the right place for initialization.
- There is always one and only one `Bundle` instance retrieved by the call to `getArguments()`, and this `Bundle` instance contains all of your `int`s, `String`s, whatever.

Comment: I agree with point one, this is one of the reasons I asked the question, might be some other reason I wasn't getting, thanks for the clarification!  ;)