# Send data from Activity to fragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have got aplication with three screens(3 fragments and viewPager), and now I want to send for example String from Activity to FragmentA but I don't know how.

This is my Activity class with pager Adapter

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

}
```

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

```
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    Fragment fragment=null;
    if(arg0==0){
        fragment=new FragmentA();


    }
    if(arg0==1){
        fragment=new FragmentB();


    }
    if(arg0==2){
        fragment=new FragmentC();


    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: You could use the solution in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503779/refresh-data-in-viewpager-fragment

Answer (score -1):

You can use the  [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library or write something similar yourself, but the best option is to learn the correct and accepted methods of communication between components.

If you want to pass the data (String in your case) before the ViewPager initialized you can pass it via argumnents, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34199095/5281581) you can find a good example.

Comment: I try this solution but my aplication was crashed.