# Using veiwpager and Fragment returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to use `ViewPager` but I get an error. Fragment returns null.
Is there something wrong in this code?

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private Bundle arguments;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
        tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));
        return v;
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    public void setArguments(Bundle arguments) {
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425568/how-to-use-setarguments-and-getarguments-methods-in-fragments

Comment: Please, post a bit more source code. For example the xml of first_fragment or the Activity, where is viewpager...

Comment: delete setArguments function